# how to make responsive images in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

There are some cards in my website that they are fine in the large and medium screens , But in the small screens the image's height will be increase !

I'm using bootstrap 5 and there is the code :

```
                        <div class="col-12 mb-4">
                        <div class="card m-auto w-100 h-100 rounded">
                            <div class="row g-0">
                                <div class="col-4 h-100">
                                    <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" class="img-fluid rounded h-100" alt="...">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p class="weblog-post-title card-title" style="font-size: 1.25rem;">{{ i.title }}</p>
                                        <p class="weblog-summery card-text text-muted">{{ post.summery|truncatechars:70 }}</p>
                                        <div class="row mt-2">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{ i.create|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}</small>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6 text-start">
                                                <a href="{{ i.get_absolute_url }}"
                                                    class="btn btn-green btn-sm mt-2" style="border-radius: 10px;">see</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

there is the picture of large screens :

[image: here the card is fine]

there is the picture of small screens:

[image: there is the problem with the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Media Queries (sm:, md:, lg:, xl:, xxl:) to make the images responsive